# Из каких функциональных блоков состоит Desktop Environment?

Tags: linux, desktop, gnome, kde, xfce

Я имею в виду, какие общие части имеют DE в Linux - Gnome3, Mate, XFCE, KDE, и другие.

Например "Менеджер окон", "Менеджер буфера обмена" - что-то в таком духе.

Это мне нужно для того, чтобы иметь представление о том, что такое DE, и как она устроена внутри. Статья на Википедии ([https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Среда_рабочего_стола](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0)) вопрос не раскрывает и конструкцию DE не описывает.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, имхо, все как обычно: драйвер видеокарты, далее библиотеки X нижнего уровня (Xt, Xwt etc), над ними упомянутые Вами менеджеры окон. И раз уж дело дошло до Википедии, то прочитайте вот это: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System

Comment: Это Вы слои графического стека описали, а не функциональные блоки, бро.